# Drush 8.1.18 not working in Drupal 7.63

Tags: 7, drush

Just updated a project to Drupal 7.63. Attempting to execute `updb` or other commands results in the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TYPO3\PharStreamWrapper\Exception: Unexpected file extension in "phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/commands/core/drupal" in /app/docroot/misc/typo3/drupal-security/PharExtensionInterceptor.php:38
```

What is the suggested fix for this?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you run the update in browser update.php?

Comment: No. It only happens on command line.

Comment: This is the latest issue relevant to you @Kevin: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3026560